# Why may the last level of 'complete binary tree' or a 'binary heap' be partially empty ? Is there a good reason for it?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, heap, binary-heap

Definition of a complete binary tree is "A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible." I wanted to know why the last level is allowed to be partially filled. Does this help in some situations/ cases?

I tried to search the answer to this question in many places however I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer. Can someone please help me by answering this. Much thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different take on this question than the other answer: If all levels would need to be completely filled you could only have trees with `(2^n)-1` elements for some `n`. I.e. 1, 3, 7, 15, ... elements. By allowing the last level to be partially filled you can have binary trees with any number of elements.

Comment: Yes.. seems very logical.. thanks. if we don't allow lower levels to be filled then we won't be able to have binary heaps/complete binary trees for a certain number of nodes !!

Answer (score 2):

That's just the definition of a complete binary tree. It does not necessarily help nor hinder anything, it just is the way it is.

If you're interested in the topic, look up balanced binary trees. There, it makes sense to only have the lowest levels not be completely filled, as to ensure that the tree is balanced and you do not have a 10 node deep left side and 1 node deep right side.

Having all of a tree's levels be completely filled help guarantee you fast search times. If all the levels are completely filled, you know the depth of the tree is equal on all possible paths, therefore ensuring you a good upper bound on search speed. In such cases you can calculate the depth of all possible leaf node paths by `D = floor(lg(N))`, where N is the number of nodes.

Now, imagine if you don't necessarily have filled levels at all. You could have something like this monstrosity, where some elements will be fetched far faster than others.

[image]